# Invalid output in `int` array

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to learn pointers and I just encountered a situation I do not understand.

```
int main()
{
  int num[3][2]={3,6,9,12,15,18};
  printf("%d %d",*(num+1)[1],**(num+2));
}
```

As per what I have learnt the output should be :

```
12 15
```

but actually it is:

```
15 15
```

Why? Please clarify as to how things are calculated here as what I think is first `*(num+1)` get calculated and point to the 1st one i.e. `{9,12}` and then `[1]` should dereference to first element i.e `12`.

I am using GCC compiler.

Comment: For more on operator precedence, [**see this table**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @WhozCraig :yeah that was really helpfull.thanks.Also can you suggest me some links or tutorials from where I could learn such and even more more complex pointer arithmetic..

Comment: @Suraj honestly there is no better substitute than simply hammering out short console apps that toy with them yourself. Particularly with *boatloads* of output using the platform-pointer format specifier `%p` for `printf`. There are a number of subtle nuances that frankly only hands-on experience can really solidify in your head. Google is your friend, as is this site. Search up `[c] pointer arithmetic` for a *plethora* of decent similar questions. And a *debugger* (single stepping and looking at vars) is *extremely* helpful.

Comment: Amongst other problems with the code, all arrays begin with 0 not 1, so a offset of [1] is actually selecting the second entry in the array.

Comment: you should first use `%p` and cast address to `void*`.

Comment: @user3629249: Why is that a problem?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: He´s printing int´s and using int pointer.arithmetic. Your suggestion breaks the code.

Comment: @deviantfan Sorry my mistake!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [C Operator Precedence,](http://de.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) `[]` is processed before `*`

That means

```
(num+1)[1]
*((num+1)+1)
*(num+2)
```

Together with the additional `*` (not written in my example),
it becomes the same as the second thing.

Comment: Operator precedence and evaluation order are orthogonal.

Comment: Ok, bad word. Better? :)

Comment: Getting there but it still implies an order of processing that's not related to the way tokens are parsed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: *orthogonal*? that would mean they are completely independent, but there are clear dependencies.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Perhaps so, but the phrase "process before" implies evaluation whereas evaluation and precedence (i.e. during parsing) are still two different things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I was referring to your comment, (so) the previous version of your comment was a lot better...

Answer (score 24):

In your data,

```
int num[3][2]={3,6,9,12,15,18};
```

equivalent to:

```
int num[3][2]={{3,6},{9,12},{15,18}};
```

i.e.

```
num[0][0] = 3
num[0][1] = 6
num[1][0] = 9
num[1][1] = 12
num[2][0] = 15
num[2][1] = 18
```

thus,

```
*(num+1)[1]
= *(*(num+1+1))
= num[2][0] 
=15
```

and,

```
**(num+2))
= num[2][0]
=15
```

Answer (score 19):

Array subscript `[]` operator has higher precedence than dereference operator `*`.

This means the expression `*(num+1)[1]` is equivalent to `*((num+1)[1])`

And if we take it apart

```
*(*((num+1)+1))

*(*(num+2))

*(num[2])

num[2][0]
```